# Eclipse RCP dynamic MenuContribution hide and unhide with CoreExpression

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm trying currently to add a `visibleWhen` condition for a MenuContribution in my Eclipse RCP application. We've different versions of our app and we've differentiate them with a `IClientConfiguration` interface/service which works more or less as feature toggles.

Depending on witch `app-$version.product` is called different implementations of the configuration will part of the app.

However.. get to the current situation: We've a menu which is defined in a common `fragment.e4xmi` and I would like to hide one menu depending on the configuration. For that I've added the toggle `isAdminMenuActive()`. I've hoped that I can create a CoreExpression and using (somehow) the return value of this service. But unfortunately I can't get this to work by now.

What I tried was the following:
fragment.e4xmi:

```xml
    <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_ZuL6oA4IEeqbk5lJVdc6WQ" elementId="com.example.client.menucontribution.administration" parentId="com.example.product.main.menu">
      <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_ngOY4LOMEemRpJf6BiOdqQ" elementId="com.example.client.menu.administration" label="%UI.general.administration">
        <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_rrmcQA4lEeqbk5lJVdc6WQ" coreExpressionId="com.example.client.configuration.adminMenuActiveExpression"/>
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_B4RqsLONEemRpJf6BiOdqQ" elementId="com.example.client.menuitem.action.administration" label="%UI.action" tooltip="%UI.action" command="_XnSp8LOPEemRpJf6BiOdqQ"/>
      </children>
    </elements>
```

plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
    <definition
       id="com.example.client.configuration.adminMenuActiveExpression">
       <with variable="com.example.client.configuration.adminMenuActive">
            <equals
                  value="true">
            </equals>
         </with>
     </definition>
</extension>
```

Startapp.java

```java
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(IEclipseContext context) {
        context.set(com.example.client.configuration.adminMenuActive,
                configuration.isAdminMenuActive().toString());
    }
```

The current behaviour is that the menu is never shown no matter which configuration is loaded. I've tried if the variable is added to the `IEclipseContext` and this happens very early in the start up phase of the application. Currently I've no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a core expression in the fragment.e4xmi you can use an 'Imperative Expression'. You do this by changing the 'Visible-When Expression' in the fragment editor.

An imperative expression specifies a Java class which is called directly making it easier to access your code. The method tagged with `@Evaluate` is called to evaluate the expression. Maybe something like:

```java
@Evaluate
public boolean evaluate(@Named("com.example.client.configuration.adminMenuActive") String active)
{
  return Boolean.valueOf(active); 
}
```

Using this makes it much easier to see what is happening.